# How can I delete my /sdcard/.xiaoniubook/ directory?

Tags: delete, sd-card

I downloaded a free book app from the Android Market and it installed just fine, but when I went to open it it told me I needed to try to delete the `/sdcard/.xiaoniubook/` directory and restart my phone. Where (or what) is that and how can I delete it?

Answer (score 2):

Have got a android sdk. If you have got it, then go to tools directory, and type:

adb shell
rm /sdcard/.xiaoniubook

Answer (score 2):

First install this awesome file manager program called ES File Explorer. [link](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)

In there browse to /sdcard.

Now press **Menu** and Select **Settings**. Go to **File Settings** and check **Show Hidden Files**

Now you should see the folder hidden folder *.xiaoniubook*. Long press it and choose **Delete** from the menu.

And just for your information, in Linux any file/folder starting with . are considered as hidden file/folder.